# Eclipse error: 'The import utils cannot be resolved'

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, entitymanager

I'm working on a simple project in Eclipse. I have an entity class. Now i should instantiate that class and store the object in the database. I have some example projects which use the JpaUtils from the utils package to do this:

```java
import utils.JpaUtils;
```

These projects run without problem.
But in my own project I get the error: 'The import utils cannot be resolved'.

I've checked the Build Path and the same libraries are included in my project as in the example projects.

Comment: Is utils.* in the same source project, or a different project? If a different project, is that project on your classpath? It might help to show a screenshot of what projects are in your workspace, and then show the project buildpath for this project so we can see how it's referring to the other projects?

Comment: Well I think no need to post screenshots. I've  forgot to check the Projects menu from the Build Path. Now I've added the Utils project and it works! Thank You! (Sorry for the silly question, I'm very new to this IDE)

Comment: No question is silly! Glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by adding the Utils project to the Build Path of my own project in the **Projects** menu, thanks to @KevinHook.